# Grails project with React showing error in my gradle.build file

Tags: reactjs, grails, terminal, grails-orm

I've just started with Grails with React for my new project. I'm following this documentation http://guides.grails.org/building-a-react-app/guide/index.html
I have done with all the setup and I'm at step 4 in the document which is running the app. But when I gave the command `$./gradlew bootRun`, it gave sme the error below:-[image]

Here is my `build.gradle` file! Please have a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
   buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:1.0.1"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:${gormVersion-".RELEASE"}"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.14.1"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:1.2.0"
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "building.a.react.app"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin:"com.moowork.node"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"
apply plugin:"org.grails.plugins.views-json"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-async"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-gsp"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.5.Final"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json:1.2.0"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json-templates:1.2.0"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:react"
    runtime "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.1.2-b03"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.14.2"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
}

bootRun {
    jvmArgs('-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always')
    addResources = true    
}

/* webpack profile */

node {
    version = '7.5.0'
    download = true
}

task bundle {
    dependsOn(['npmInstall', 'npm_run_bundle'])
}

task webpack {
    dependsOn(['npmInstall', 'npm_run_webpack'])
}

bootRun.dependsOn(['bundle'])
assetCompile.dependsOn(['bundle'])

/* react profile */

task mochaTest {
    dependsOn(['npmInstall', 'npm_run_test'])
}

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not using the exact command to run the grails app. The command is `grails run-app`. When running this command for the first time, it will download all the dependencies, and take some time to start the server. After the first time, next time when someone run the app, the server will start quickly.